# How to connect to SQL Server 2014 with datagrip

Tags: sql-server-2014, datagrip

My SQL Server Management Studio is working but datagrip is not connecting to SQL Server. My local instance is `IMZZA\sqlserver2014`

[image]

Comment: BTW, users, check this tutorial: https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2016/06/21/connecting-datagrip-to-ms-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

For instance "IMZZA\sqlserver2014", you have to enter like:

1. Host = IMZZA
2. Instance = sqlserver2014
3. Also Remove the value from Port, which is default 1433
4. Click "Test Connection" button. It should give you the "Connection successful" message.

These steps worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that TCP must be enabled in Config Manager
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This only worked for me with SQL Server Browser Enabled and Running.

[image]